# authenticate_or_request_with_http_token fails even when the token matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
def restrict_access
  # raise ApiKey.exists?(access_token: params[:token]).to_s
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
    ApiKey.exists?(access_token: token)
  end
end
```

`ApiKey.exists?(access_token: token)` returns `true`, yet every time this def is called it returns a `HTTP Token: Access denied.` and I have no idea why. I can even hard code the correct token and it still fails. It only seems to do this in dev and test, but works in prod which scares me. It also just started happening seemingly out of the blue. I can't even debug anything within the authenticate_or_request_with_http_token block, it's kicking me out before ApiKey.exists?() is even executed.

I've looked at the source but it's not all that helpful to me.
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/04cda1848cb847c2bdad0bfc12160dc8d5547775/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/http_authentication.rb#L393

Comment: Take a look at the logs to see what the SQL is.

Comment: I have the same problem here using Rails 4.0, have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score -1):

There is a note in the docs, maybe you have this problem:

> On shared hosts, Apache sometimes doesn’t pass authentication headers
>   to FCGI instances. If your environment matches this description and
>   you cannot authenticate, try this rule in your Apache setup:
>
> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi [E=X-HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},QSA,L]
> ```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Token.html